# CountDown in React Native (Display order of minutes and seconds)

Tags: react-native, countdown

I'm using react-native-countdown-component. my code is:

```
<CountDown
             timeToShow={['M', 'S']}
             timeLabels={{ m: '', s: '' }}
             digitStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
              showSeparator={true}
             until={this.state.until}
              size={moderateScale(20)}
           />
```

My problem is that it shows seconds first, then minutes!!!(from left to right) there isn't any styles. why?????!!!

[image]

Comment: What is the parent element of it?

Answer (score 0):

there is no parent element. my code is just:

```
const App: () => React$Node = () => {
 render() { 
 return ( 
 <CountDown 
 timeToShow={['M', 'S']} 
  timeLabels={{ m: '', s: '' }} 
 digitStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }} 
 showSeparator={true} until={this.state.until} 
 size={moderateScale(20)} /> 
  ) 
 }
```

}

but output is:[image]

While  must show firse minute, then second!!!(from left to right)